# Image swap with CSS — flicker issue

Tags: css

I am trying to swap an image with CSS but when the mouse rolls over for the first time, instead of one image being replaced with another one, I get a flicker first. Here's my CSS code:

```
#UL {
    width: 50px;
    height: 54px;
    background:url("/img/UL_gr.png") no-repeat;     
}
#UL:hover {
    background-image:url("/i/logos/UL.png");        
}
```

Comment: Maybe image isn't loaded yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preload your images and use sprites.  Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Is the flicker perhaps because of the browser trying to load in the new image (UL.png?)

Just to see, try adding an img element with "/i/logos/UL.png" as the src and display: none as the inline style. Add that somewhere on your page and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The flicker is because the image is not loaded yet, you should preload it.  There's a number of ways to do this, below is one method.  It doesn't show in the page but since it's in the body it will still load the image.  Put this below all your other content so it doesn't slow down the loading of anything else.

```
<div style="display:none;">
   <img src="/i/logos/UL.png" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is most likely, that the browser has not yet loaded the image. You can do the preload as described on [this page](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/simple_rollover_button/).